# condition in partial from other controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views, conditional-statements

I have a model group -> has_many :questions and a question -> has_many :votes

In my my view show, for the controller groups, I have a partial that can display the list of the questions :
`<%= render :partial => 'question', :collection => @group.questions.byvote %>` 
Then I have a link to vote with a style like this :

```
<%= link_to(question_votes_path(question), :controller => :vote, :action => :create, :method => :post, :id => 'vote') do %>
<%= image_tag("voteUp.png")%>
<%= question.votes_count%>
<%end%>
```

What I would like to do is make a condition, like :

```
    <% if canvote?%>
```

… and change the style of the div.

BUT. Making a condition in the group controller can't be made because I need to make my request about the question and not about the group  :

```
Vote.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :question_id => @question.id).first
```

How can I make it form the other controller group or tell an helper_method in the question controller ?

Comment: what does `canvote?` ideally tell you?  what are the conditions under which a user can vote?

Comment: It tell me if exist a record "vote" from the current_user for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use a model method - you can then call it right in the view and do so unobtrusively.  The following method will return `true` if the user has voted on a given `question`:

**User.rb**

```
def voted?(question)
  #returns true if vote exists
  Vote.exists?(:user_id => current_user.id, :question_id => question.id) 
end
```

You can use it like this:

**_question.html.erb**

```
<% if current_user.voted?(@question) %>
  #code to use if the user has voted on this question
<% else %>
  #code to use if the user has NOT voted on this question
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks ! Works perfectly.I just have to add `current_user = UserSession.find.user` in model.

Comment: great, glad it worked :)  you could also use `:user_id => self.id`